# How to filter a column by a range with Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to filter a Power Query column by a range of values. I see that I can manually select or deselect values from the column, but I need to do this automatically absed on a range of values already in the sheet.

Let's say the table I'm querying contains 100 unique names. I only want to import rows that match a list of 20 names I have in my sheet.

How can I do this with Power Query?

Edit: I can make an excel function to concatenate a list of names into the format needed for the query like this:  `(= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Ticket Assignee] ="Name 1" or [Ticket Assignee] ="Name 2")))`. But still need a way to reference this from the query.

Edit2:

**My query:**

This errors out with:

> Expression.Error: We expected a FieldsSelector value.

```
let
    names_Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="namesTable"]}[Content],
    names_Values = names_Source{1},


    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type datetime}, {"Ticket Assignee", type text}, {"# Solved", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Ticket Assignee] <> null)),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each Record.HasFields(names_Values, [Ticket Assignee]))
in
    #"Filtered Rows1"
```

**Edit3**: Modified Query:

> Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value null to type Record.
>   Details:
>       Value=
>       Type=Type

```
let
    names_Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="namesTable"]}[Content],
    names_Values = Record.FromList(names_Source[Zendesk Name], names_Source[Zendesk Name]),


    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type datetime}, {"Ticket Assignee", type text}, {"# Solved", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Ticket Assignee] <> null)),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each Record.HasFields(names_Values, [Ticket Assignee]))
in
    #"Filtered Rows1"
```

**Edit4**: My table has blank values that were erroring out as null. I added a line to filter out the null values from my names source

Comment: Don't use `names_Values = names_Source{1}`, instead use `names_Value = Record.FromList(names_Source[Column1], names_Source[Column1])`. You got the FieldSelector error because `#"Filtered Rows1"` refers to the wrong table: you want to filter on `#"Filtered Rows"`, not on `#"Changed Type"`

Comment: @AlejandroLopez-Lago-MSFT Ah, good catch on the field selector. I've made the changes you requested, now I'm receiving the 2nd error, `We cannot convert the value null to type Text.`. Is there a way to debug the query to see the exact point or field of failure?

Again, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list of items you want to check against is in an Excel worksheet, then you can import the table using From Table and use `List.Contains` to see if your values are in that table. If the worksheet table is in WorksheetQuery and the names are in the column Names, then your step would look like:

`= Table.SelectRows(PreviousStep, each List.Contains(WorksheetQuery[Names], [Ticket Assignee]))`

If that ends up being too slow, you can try to convert the column into a record and then using `Record.HasFields` instead.

Comment: What would `WorksheetQuery` be? Is that an imported range or table, or can you actually import queries into the query editor? I've created a table and referenced it like so: `names_Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=names]}[Content],
    names_Value = names_Source{0}[Value],` what next steps are needed to get that into the filter in the manner shown?

Comment: The `list.contains` is pretty slow (It's been running for ~10 minutes), and I only have a few days worth of data (80k rows). Tried the Record.HasField route, but ended up with a blank table

Comment: WorksheetQuery is whatever query the From Table action created. For Record.HasFields, how does your query look like? I convert the list with `Record = Record.FromList(names_Value, names_Value)`, then use `Table.SelectRows(PreviousStep, each Record.HasFields(Record, [Ticket Assignee]))`.

Comment: I have updated my question with my current query. The `names_Values = names_Source{1},` appears to be a record, so there is no need to convert it. However, for kicks I did convert it to a list, then back to a record just to test and got the same results. I added the errors I am currently receiving as well. Thank you for the help thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't to use join operations? It seems like it works at least not slower, but more clear, in my mind:

```
let
    names_Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="namesTable"]}[Content],
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Joind = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Ticket Assignee"},names_Source,{"Zendesk Name"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.RightOuter),
    Filtered = Table.RemoveColumns(Joind,{"NewColumn"})
in
    Filtered
```

Comment: It's definitely easier to use join operations - you don't need to write any code at all, just use the Merge button in the Query Editor UI.